# is this erlnag cassandra client support cqlsh3?

Tags: erlang, cassandra, ejabberd

https://github.com/ostinelli/erlcassa
 I am using this erlang cassandra client is support cqlsh3 features. As i tried composite column and select query with allow filtering are not supported this client is there any solution for that features support.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra CQL3 is a new iteration of CQL. And while erlcassa supports CQL but it is obviously that it doesn't support CQL3 (considering the source files are two years old).

Comment: thank for reply is there any erlcassandra client for cql3 supported,can u suggesst me.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use the [Erlcass](https://github.com/silviucpp/erlcass) driver which is based on the native [datastax cpp driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver).

In the config you need to specify the `protocol_version` in order to change the default value.